# Converting from R POSIXlt to T-Sql datetime

Tags: sql-server, r, datetime, posixct, posixlt

I need to restructure the R POSIXlt object into an appropriate T-SQL query that is going to return a SQL datetime. I imagine there should be a way to conver the POSIXlt to a double and then use that double to make a SQL datetime, but I am not able to figure out how exactly to do that. Here is what I have tried:

```
date = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
date_num = as.double(date)
```

After that I copied the contents of date_num (1469491570) and attempted to paste it into the following SQL query to see what happens:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), 1469491570));
```

However, this errors out, which I guess is expected, since it expects a string representation of a date not some random number...

EDIT: I am looking to find something that can convert the POSIXlt to a number of tics or milliseconds from, say, 1900 and then uses that number to create a T-SQL datetime.

Comment: the function `julian(x, origin = as.Date("1970-01-01"), ...)`  can convert the POSIX object to the number of days to your specified origin then you should be able to convert to the number of seconds or milliseconds.

Comment: @Dave2e that actually is exactly what I wanted. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function:

```
julian(x, origin = as.Date("1970-01-01"), ...)
```

can convert the POSIX object to the number of days to your specified origin then you should be able to convert to the number of seconds or milliseconds.

For example:

```
as.numeric(julian(as.Date("2016-07-25")))
```

is 17007 days from Jan 1, 1970 (Beginning of time for Unix) or

```
as.numeric(julian(as.Date("2016-07-25"), origin = as.Date("1900-01-01")))
```

or 42574 days from close to the beginning of time for windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear because you keep talking about "dates" but appear to want times (duration in small intervals since a reference date). Try this:

```
      date = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
      date_num = as.numeric( as.POSIXct(date) ) # should now be seconds from MN 1970-01-01
```

Noting further that `Sys.time()` would have been POSIXct-class. According to this there is a TSQL datetime with a format exactly as you would see from format.POSIXt using the default values for the 'format' argument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx, so you might even try (with suitable class definition of the receiving columns:

```
date = format( as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()) )
date     # now a character value
#[1] "2016-07-25 18:48:08"
```